# Php PDO is not updating have no idea why

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

Here is my code:

```
$page = 'home';
$data = 'blah blah blah';
// my database connection (i know there is no problems here);
require_once('../inc/connection.php');
$id = 1;
$values = array(
    ':page' => $page,
    ':id' => $id,
    ':data' => $data
);
$query = 'UPDATE site SET :page=:data WHERE id=:id';
$sql = $conn->prepare($query);
$sql->execute($values);
// this prints out perfect
echo 'UPDATE site SET '.$page.'='.$data.' WHERE id='.$id;
```

When I run this page it prints the echo at the end, but when I check my site table it does not reflect the update.  I have no idea what I am doing.  The connection is good because I am making select queries just fine.

Comment: just to double check, does the update query run ok outside of php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Table and Column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter)

so

```
$query = 'UPDATE `site` 
          SET `page`=:data 
          WHERE id=:id';
```

A query should do a specific thing, if you need dynamic columns then perhaps put them in an `if` or `switch` statement, or build a database model that handles this with class methods that handle column variations ect.